# elfファイルの特定のシンボルの中身を後から差し替えたい

Tags: c++, c

例えばC言語で下記のように128バイトの領域を確保したとします。

```
const char TABLE[128] = {0};
```

このシンボルを含んだオブジェクトファイルをリンクして生成されたelfファイルに対して、後からTABLEが指すアドレスの中身を差し替える、ということがやりたいのです。

elfフォーマットを勉強して、シンボルテーブルをパースして・・・といった手順を踏めば実現できそうに思えますが、今回はそこまで手間をかけている時間もないので、何かツールでできればと思っています。

対称はARMのelfです。binutilsのツールでどうにかできないでしょうか？

Comment: 普通にスタックに割り付ける場合（実行時のアドレスを推定するのは）難しいように思います。なので、置き換えるための実際の文字列を割り当てる必要があると思います。この場合constなのでstaticにして例えば`const char TABLE[128] = "abracadabra"; 等としておいてバリナリエディタで検索・置換すればいいかと思います。
`

Comment: 私はwindows環境なので知りませんが、elfってファイルの内容に対してＣＲＣのような検証符号を持っていて実行に際し不正な書き換えを察知するようになっていたりしませんかね？

Comment: 今回の場合、実行時のアドレスが必要なのではなく、elfファイル中のオフセットがわかれば、そのオフセットから128バイト分を置き換えれば目的を達成できるのではないかと思ってます。

その場合でも適当な文字列をマーキング代わりにしておけば探しやすいかもしれないですね。

TABLE[]はグローバル領域に確保します。staticにするとシンボルテーブルに残らないんじゃなかろーかと思い、意図的にstaticなしとしています。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY さんの方法を x86_64 の Linux で やって見ましたが、問題なく動きました。（あまり詳しくないので、回答にはしません）

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readelf` コマンドを使って、まずは `TABLE` 変数の「メモリアドレス」を表示してみます。ソースコードは yaegashi さんの回答にあるものと同じであるとします。

```
$ gcc -g -o a a.c # デバッグオプションを付ける
$ readelf -s a | grep -w TABLE
    70: 080484e0   128 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 TABLE
```

`TABLE` 変数のメモリアドレスは `080484e0` となっています。`TABLE` 変数が格納されている場所を調べてみると、

```
$ objdump -t a | grep -w TABLE
SYMBOL TABLE:
080484e0 g     O .rodata    00000080              TABLE
```

`.rodata` セクションであることが判ります。

次に、ELF の `.rodata` セクションの情報を表示します。

```
$ LC_MESSAGES=C readelf -S a | sed -rn '/^Section Headers:/,+1p;/\.rodata/{p;q;}'
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS        080484c0 0004c0 0000a0 00   A  0
```

`TABLE` 変数のメモリアドレスは `080484e0`、`.rodata` セクションは `080484c0` で、ファイルオフセットは `0004c0` です。したがって、`TABLE` 変数のファイルオフセットは以下の様にして求めることができます。

```
$ echo $((0x80484e0 - 0x80484c0 + 0x4c0))
1248
```

それでは実際に `TABLE` 変数の内容を書き換えてみましょう。

```
$ printf 'Hello World!' | dd of=a bs=1 seek=1248 count=12 conv=notrunc
12+0 records in
12+0 records out
12 bytes copied, 0.00128388 s, 9.3 kB/s
$ ./a
Hello World!
```

Comment: こちらの方法で上手くいきました。ありがとうございます。ビルドスクリプトでGitのハッシュ値を自動的に埋め込んだりと、色々と面白い使い方ができそうです。
arm-none-eabi-gccでは.rodataではなく、.textに定数は配置されるようでした。

Answer (score 2):

`gdb --write` を使うと手軽、かもしれません。 実行するわけではないので、ターゲットが ARM でもクロス gdb が使えると思います。

ただし、手元の Ubuntu 16.10 (amd64) の GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.90.20161005-0ubuntu1) では終了時に Segmentation fault となったり、書き換えが反映されなかったりと、動作があやしいです。  [Use gdb to Modify Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26173850/4937930) なども参照してください。

```
$ cat hoge.c
#include <stdio.h>
const char TABLE[128] = {0};
int main() { printf("%s\n", TABLE); return 0; }

$ cat hoge.gdb
set *(0 + (char *)&TABLE) = 'h'
set *(1 + (char *)&TABLE) = 'o'
set *(2 + (char *)&TABLE) = 'g'
set *(3 + (char *)&TABLE) = 'e'
p TABLE ← これをやらないと書き換えが反映されない…
quit

$ gcc -g hoge.c
$ gdb --write -q -x hoge.gdb a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
$1 = "hoge", '\000' <repeats 123 times>
Segmentation fault (コアダンプ)
$ ./a.out
hoge
```

Answer (score 1):

まずソースの例は他の方の回答そのままで。

```
$ cat hoge.c
#include <stdio.h>
const char TABLE[128] = {0};
int main() { printf("%s\n", TABLE); return 0; }
$ gcc hoge.c
```

`const char` なら定数なので .rodata セクションに書かれるはずなので

```
hdr=$(objdump -h a.out | fgrep .rodata)
set -- $hdr
RODATA_VMA=$4
RODATA_OFFSET=$6
```

と、まず `.rodata` セクションの VMA とファイルオフセットを取得し、次に

```
TABLE_VMA=$(objdump -t -j .rodata a.out | awk '($6 == "TABLE"){print $1}')
```

で `TABLE` の相対アドレスを取得、最後にそのファイルオフセット計算します

```
file_addr=$(awk "END{print 0x${RODATA_OFFSET} + 0x${TABLE_VMA} - 0x${RODATA_VMA}}" /dev/null)
```

必ずあるであろう awk を使ってますが、hex address の計算ができれば他のツールでも何でもいいです。最後に、書き換えは dd で

```
printf 'hoge\x00' | dd of=a.out bs=1 seek=${file_addr} conv=notrunc 
./a.out
hoge
```

dd でのバイナリ編集は http://qiita.com/albatross/items/a2e3c690875b321096d7 を参考にしました。

VMA と SYMBOL のアドレスが一致しない場合のチェックとか色々セーフティーチェックがないし、私も ELF フォーマットについては全く知らない（適当に web と man 読んだだけ、学習時間約１時間）ので、at your own risk でお願いします。